# Typescript React.Js File Upload Event Ts2322 Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hi I am very new to React.js and typescript.I am trying to upload a simple file along with simple inputs.

I examined some examples([ex1](https://gist.github.com/AshikNesin/e44b1950f6a24cfcd85330ffc1713513),[ex2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666036/typescript-react-setstate-with-user-input?rq=1),[ex3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168659/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-from-react-js-with-an-image)) related with file uploading or input element events  on the web but I couldn't make any of them to work.

Here is my tsx file.

```
import * as React from 'react';
//import * as $ from "jquery";
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, FormText } from 'reactstrap';
interface UploadContainerState {

    tcknVkn: number;
    proclamationYear: number;
    file: FileList|null;
}
export default class UploadContainer extends React.Component<{}, UploadContainerState> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            proclamationYear: 0,
            tcknVkn: 0,
            file: null
        }
        this.proclamationYearChange = this.proclamationYearChange.bind(this);
        this.tcknVknChange = this.tcknVknChange.bind(this);
        this.uploadFile = this.uploadFile.bind(this);
        this.fileChange = this.fileChange.bind(this);

    }
    proclamationYearChange(event: any) {
        this.setState({ proclamationYear: event.target.value });
    }
    tcknVknChange(event: any) {
        this.setState({ tcknVkn: event.target.value });
    }
    fileChange(event: any) {
        this.setState({ file: event.target.files[0] });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <form className="uploader" encType="multipart/form-data" >
                    <br />
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="proclamationYear">Beyanname Yılı</Label>
                        <Input type="text" name="proclamationYear" id="proclamationYear" placeholder="Beyanname Yılını Giriniz." onChange={this.proclamationYearChange} value={this.state.proclamationYear} />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="tcknVkn">Tckn/Vkn</Label>
                        <Input type="text" name="tcknVkn" id="tcknVkn" placeholder="Tckn/Vkn Giriniz." onChange={this.tcknVknChange} value={this.state.tcknVkn} />
                    </FormGroup>

                    <input  type="file" name="file" className="upload-file" onChange={this.fileChange} value={this.state.file} />
                    <input type="button"  value="Beyanname Yükle" onClick={this.uploadFile} />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
    uploadFile(event: any) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', event.target.myimage.files[0]);
        formData.append('tcknVkn', event.target.tcknVkn.value);
        formData.append('proclamationYear', event.target.proclamationYear.value);
        fetch('ProposalData/UploadFile', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: formData
        })
    }
};
```

I am receiving following error.

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/UploadContainer.tsx:50:29 
    TS2322: Type '{ type: "file"; name: "file"; className: "upload-file"; onChange: (event: any) => void; value: Fi...' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.
  Type '{ type: "file"; name: "file"; className: "upload-file"; onChange: (event: any) => void; value: Fi...' is not assignable to type 'InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>'.
    Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
      Type 'FileList | null' is not assignable to type 'string | number | string[] | undefined'.
        Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | number | string[] | undefined'.
```

Here is my typescript version 5.6.0

I can't understand how can such easy task becomes a nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not the optimal solution.But here is complete back-end and front-end code for those who are trying to accomplish same task using .net core,react.js and typescript.

Here is my tsx file note that I commented file property in my interface and made it public property.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, FormText } from 'reactstrap';
import ListGroup from 'reactstrap/lib/ListGroup';

interface UploadContainerState {

    tcknVkn: number;
    proclamationYear: number;
    alertVisible: boolean;

    //file: FileList
}
export default class UploadContainer extends React.Component<{}, UploadContainerState> {
    public file: File;
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            proclamationYear: 0,
            tcknVkn: 0,
            alertVisible: false
        }
        this.proclamationYearChange = this.proclamationYearChange.bind(this);
        this.tcknVknChange = this.tcknVknChange.bind(this);
        this.uploadFile = this.uploadFile.bind(this);
        this.fileChange = this.fileChange.bind(this);

    }
    proclamationYearChange(event: any) {
        this.setState({ proclamationYear: event.target.value });
    }
    tcknVknChange(event: any) {
        this.setState({ tcknVkn: event.target.value });
    }
    onDismiss() {
        this.setState({ alertVisible: false });
    }

    fileChange(event: any) {
        this.file = event.target.files[0];
        event.preventDefault();

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <form onSubmit={this.uploadFile} className="uploader" encType="multipart/form-data" >
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="proclamationYear">Year</Label>
                        <Input type="text" name="proclamationYear" id="proclamationYear"  onChange={this.proclamationYearChange} value={this.state.proclamationYear} />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="tcknVkn">Tckn/Vkn</Label>
                        <Input type="text" name="tcknVkn" id="tcknVkn"  onChange={this.tcknVknChange} value={this.state.tcknVkn} />
                    </FormGroup>

                    <input type="file" name="file" accept=".pdf" className="upload-file" onChange={this.fileChange} />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
    uploadFile(event: any) {
        let that = this;
        event.preventDefault();
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', this.file);
        formData.append('tcknVkn', event.target.tcknVkn.value);
        formData.append('proclamationYear', event.target.proclamationYear.value);
        fetch("ProposalData/UploadFile", {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, */*',
            },
            body: formData
        })
            .then(handleErrors)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("ok");
            }).catch(function (error) {

                console.log(error);
            });
    }
};
function handleErrors(response: any) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Here is my controller

```
public class FileUploadModel
{
    public string ProclamationYear { get; set; }
    public string TcknVkn { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromForm]FileUploadModel vm)
        {
            var file = vm.File;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a mismatch in value property type. Expected is `string | number | string[] | undefined` while you are passing in `FileList`

You cannot set value of file input due to security reason. The only way to set file input's value is via user action in browser. Remove `value={this.state.file}` and it will compile.

Besides that, the type of the state field should be `File`

Comment: I removed value={this.state.file} and changed file type to string UploadContainerState {
    file: string;
} and assign  empty string to file:
      this.state = {

            file: ''
        }
this time code compiles but I hit submit button this error appears.
UploadContainer.tsx:59 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined
What should be the type of file ?

Comment: Change the  state field type to File

Comment: But this time you can't assign it null